# How to remove rows that are pulled using the which() function

Tags: r

```
Df <-  which(Df == 'NA') 
Df <- Df [lapply(Df, "%%", 2) == 1]
```

Identifying which rows are incorrect and then pulling only the odd numbers. I then would like to remove the rows that match the numbers pulled. Any ideas for how to go about doing this?

Comment: There's quite a few potential problems here, for just 2 lines of code. `%%` is vectorized, no need for `lapply`. But I think the biggest issue is that you're using the same name `Df` for both the data frames and the indexes. And, do you want to be looking at a particular column? And lastly if you are finding string values "NA" then `== "NA"` will work, but if you have missing values `is.na()` is the way to find them.

Comment: So, with all those potential issues, could you please share a sample of your data reproducibly? Something like `dput(head(Df, 10))` for the first 10 rows -- choose a suitable subset. `dput()` will give a copy/pasteable version that includes all class and structure information.

Comment: first, which does not return a dataframe but rather a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. I assume that Df is a `data.frame` and that you want to remove the odd rows that have a `NA`. In that case, you can do

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:3,NA), b = c(NA, 2:4))
i <- which(apply(is.na(df), 1, any))

odd <- i[(i%%2) != 0] 
#[1] 1
df[-odd, ]
#   a b
#2  2 2
#3  3 3
#4 NA 4
```